# How to do multiple select using PostgresSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I have two tables:
`destination` and `weather_forecast` and I am getting lastest weather_forecast (order by `reference_time`) like this:

```
SELECT destination_id, reference_time FROM weather_forecast 
WHERE destination_id = (SELECT id FROM destination WHERE slug = 'prague') 
AND reference_time < now()
ORDER BY reference_time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

For slug `prague` (Prague city).

I need to do this query for a thousand cities...

Definitely it is not optimal to call this using loop:

```
const SLUG_LIST = ['prague', 'new-york', .... next 1000 items]
const weather = db.select...
```

Is there any better way how to do it using some optimal way? Some select base on a list of items from array?

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a job for `join`.

Comment: Can you just use `WHERE slug IN ('prague', 'new-york', …)` or `WHERE slug = ANY('{prague, new-york, …}'::text[])`? Or do you need the last forecast for each city?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to rank weather forecasts by descending `reference_time` for each destination, and then filter on the most recent forecast:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        d.slug,
        w.destination_id, 
        w.reference_time,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY w.destination_id ORDER BY w.reference_time DESC) rn
    FROM weather_forecast w
    INNER JOIN destination d ON d.id = w.destination_id
    WHERE w.reference_time < now()
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: There is a probably syntax error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 9:   INNER JOIN destination d.id = w.destination_id`

Comment: @jimodefax: I just fixed a typo, please give it another try?

Comment: Thank you, now it's working. Thank you for your advice and help.